# Fatal error: Call to undefined function in database.php

Tags: function, undefined, php

**UPDATE Suddenly - without changing anything -  it works again ON SOME PAGES, on others it doesn't even show the result of my function function_exists('decod'), any ideas why?**

I get this error:

> **Fatal error: Call to undefined function decod() in database.php on line 10**

It worked fine before, here's database.php:

```
//Decode base64
function decod($string){ 
  $string = base64_decode($string); 
  return ($string); 
} 

//Data double-coded with base64, just to prevent people reading
$host = "localhost";
$user = decod(DOUBLE_ENCRYPTED_USERNAME);
$pass = decod(DOUBLE_ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD);
$db = decod(DOUBLE_ENCRYPTED_DATABASE);

//Connect or print error
$con = mysql_connect($host, decod($user), decod($pass));
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//Select database
mysql_select_db(decod($db), $con);
```

Comment: what's `DOUBLE_ENCRYPTED_USERNAME` is it your constant?

Comment: Suddenly - without changing anything -  it works again ON SOME PAGES, on others it doesn't even show the result of my function_exists('decod'). Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Human error - turns out my website was pointing at the wrong database.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, the interpreter cannot find your function `decod()`. Whatever it does and whereever it is located, it must be included somewhere in your code.

Comment: Look at the top, i am pretty sure i defined decod()

Comment: Try a `function_exists('decod')` to verify that.

Comment: I put it in: //Decode bae64 function decod($string){ $string = base64_decode($string); return ($string); } if (function_exists('decod')) { echo "Decod() is working<br />\n"; } else { echo "Decod() isn't working<br />\n"; } but now it gives me this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function decod() in database.php on line 10 It doesn't even say if decod exists

Comment: what is line 10 in this case?

Comment: It's already solved. One of my pages whas pointing at the wrong database.php

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the function is defined in your current file or not using

```
 function_exists ( string $function_name )
```

Comment: I put it in: `//Decode bae64
function decod($string){ 
  $string = base64_decode($string); 
  return ($string); 
} 

if (function_exists('decod')) {
    echo "Decod() is working<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "Decod() isn't working<br />\n";
}` but now it gives me this error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function decod() in database.php on line 10** It doesn't even say if  decod exists